# How can I use headless Chrome Developer Tools to view Protractor progress without interfering with the test?

Tags: docker, protractor, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-headless

**Background**

I'm working on end-to-end tests for an Angular 2 application. My Protractor capabilities is configured with the Chrome browser with an option to run in headless mode. I've created a Docker Compose stack to run the E2E tests with a headless Chrome in a [container](https://hub.docker.com/r/trion/ng-cli/). It works well but I can't see what the specs are doing in the browser when running the stack. I have to run the tests outside the stack in windowed mode to get graphical feedback.

**Problem**

I would like to use the E2E stack and connect to the Chrome Developer Tools Remote Debugging Front-end (via `chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com`) on port `9222`. The DevTools is great because it has a window showing what the headless browser is doing and all of the great tooling. Unfortunately, the screen cast seems to be interfering with the test cases when opened. Button clicks fail and random text gets selected. Running the tests without the screen cast preview window avoids the problem, but then I can't see what's going on.

**Question**

Is there a way to run my Protractor tests against a Headless Chrome that allows me to access the Chrome Developer Tools Remote Debugging Front-end while the tests are running without affecting the results?

**Research**

I've looked into the Chrome [capabilities](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities) and Chrome [options](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) but I can't find something that would enable a "view only" device window. I've also considered using VNC remote-desktop but I would prefer to have an integrated development experience. I'm thinking that a combination of using VNC and Chrome DevTools might be a good compromise if the DevTools preview can't be used.

**Configuration**

```js
function buildChromeArgs() {
    const args = [
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
        '--window-size=1920,1080',
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--force-device-scale-factor=1',
        '--remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0',
        '--remote-debugging-port=9222'
    ];

    if (headless == true || headless == 'true') {
        args.push('--headless');
    }

    return args;
}
```

```js
multiCapabilities: [
    {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'chromeOptions': {
            'args': buildChromeArgs()
        },
    },
]
```